# SQLite Select query sometimes returns a random number

Tags: sqlite, ios8

I have recently upgraded the app I was working on to work with IOS 8, it all works fine.
However, sometimes when I start the application my SQLite SELECT query returns:

```
322027609095939383707792575607519049745533997457083986970229508889061718536004240161547019569861752725561453245069316208671532472953637165437644212189011829130655476571403671022488303200932764265703966515944712440546988860820727338331302000475693699091660800.000000

84902528013508089164778277091711377903148050997045969503110252996583267358608226520193514416555326678785596608608177469762862141711497480246768422703670157146950930769110892544.000000
```

as the values stored on those rows, this is incorrect as there are no values there yet. This error then solves itself the next time I try to access that data - returning the correct values of 0.000000 and 0.000000.

Any ideas why??

P.S.

I haven't included any code with this, I can if it's necessary - but I thought as it was working before on IOS4 and it's an intermittent error it wasn't an issue with the code.

Comment: There are two long numbers in your pasted text, separated by a comma, by the way. One 259 digits left of the decimal, the other has 176.

Comment: There were meant to be, i just worded it badly, correction have been made now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it must have been something to do with the way the value was stored, accessing a NUMBER from an SQL schema and converting it to a double seemed to sometimes return a random value.

Changing the value to an NSNumber seemed to solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The first number, when converted to hex, looks like this (214 hex digits, 107 bytes):

```
AB937B19732B6000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

The second number looks like this (148 hex digits, 74 bytes):

```
015746974616C600000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

I don't know what significance those numbers have. They don't look like ASCII strings of any kind. Perhaps they're just noise left in an uninitialized location.